# Is there a way to hide static region title

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using static region in oracle apex 5.1 and I want the title not to be visible. Is there a way to hide region title?

I have tried different templates as well as searching the internet but was not able to find anything relevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the region properties palette, under Appearance click on Template Options:
[image]

In there you can set the region title to Hidden (Or Hidden but accessible):
[image]

Comment: I already have Header set to hidden but the title still showing up

Comment: That sounds wrong - can you recreate the issue on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: my bad, the image on the region was named the same as the region itself so it was not region title but image label

Answer (score 1):

Click on Region
In properties > Appearance > Template > Blank With Attributes
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zuqY.png)